# Detect if facebook page plugin is loaded

Tags: jquery, facebook, onload

I need to know when the Facebook page plugin is loaded, because sometimes it takes a lot of time, and it leaves a white space.

I've embedded the page plugin as [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) said

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=XXXXXXX";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And then as the facebook's [example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin):

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

It works ok, but I need to know when it's loaded, so I can show it after all.

---

UPDATE

After lot of days, I just hide the box and show it after 1 minute, but sometimes it still not load the page. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You can subscribe to the event of all FB plugins on the page having be “rendered” (see JS SDK docs for details) – but that doesn’t necessarily mean the content is loaded already, it just means the `<div class="fb-something">` elements have been injected the iframes used to request and show the content.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, but when my page load faster than the facebook page plugin, so this last one make's an awful white box for a while.

Comment: Well then give that box a non-awful, non-white background …?

Comment: Not possible. I can hide the box and show it after Facebook plugin loads, but when ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', function(response) {
        console.log('rendered.... finally!');
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isFacebookContentLoaded()
{
     const iframeContent = $('#fb-root .fb_dialog .fb_dialog_content iframe');
    if(iframeContent.length > 0)
    {
                    $('.tap-chat a').on('click', function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            const fbDialogMaxHeight     = $("#fb-root .fb_iframe_widget iframe:first");
                            (fbDialogMaxHeight.css("maxHeight") == "0px") 
                                        ? FB.CustomerChat.show() 
                                        : FB.CustomerChat.hide();
                    });
    }
    return false;
}
// If the content is not loaded yet, set up an interval to keep checking.
var checkInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (isFacebookContentLoaded() !== false) {
        clearInterval(checkInterval);
    }
}, 1000);
// Check every 1 second
```